# Capture WebSocket audio file with Chrome Devtools

Tags: azure, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, mp3, text-to-speech

I would like to know if it is possible to capture the audio that plays through the Websocket protocol using Chrome DevTools

Under Network, I do see a Websocket entry after the audio begins to play.
It is listed as wss://eastus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/websocket/v1?Authorization=RandomCharacterConnectionId=IDGoesHere

I checked it's Headers and Messages but it seems there is no way to get a hold of the audio file.

Any suggestions?
Example is here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-to-speech/

Thanks

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Comment: I created a .html file with this code but it won't work for me. I put the full URL for microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js and it downloads an empty mp3 file.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the config that works for me(with a free service tier), pls have a try , and let me know if it works.

Comment: Where can I get the microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js file from?

Comment: You can download the file here:https://aka.ms/csspeech/jsbrowserpackage . BTW, if my post is helpful, pls click the checkmark beside my answer to accept it. This action will close this question and help others who has similar issue.

Comment: I extracted that file in the same folder as my test.html with your code and it still creates a 9KB mp3 file that does not play every single time ....

Comment: @TylerDurden How is it going? I have the SAME exact use case as you!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to save the resulting audio as .mp3 file, just try code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript Quickstart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  
  <button id="startSpeakTextAsyncButton" onclick="synthesizeSpeech()">speak</button>
  
  <script src="microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.sdk.bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
    function synthesizeSpeech() {
        
        var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("", "");
        
        speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisLanguage = "en-US";
        
        const synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
        "Hello , this is a demo about saving result of TTS API as a file",
        result => {
            synthesizer.close();
            const link = document.createElement( 'a' );
            link.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild( link );


            const blob = new Blob( [result.audioData], { type: 'audio/mp3' } ); 
            const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
             
            link.href = objectURL;
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
            link.download =  'data.mp3';
            link.click();
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            synthesizer.close();
        });
    }
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**structure**:
[image]

**Result:**

[image]

[image]